# Google DNS Geolocation Issue

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, google, isp, geolocation

I work on a ISP in Africa. Our customers were being redirected to Google cache in South Africa. Apparently with no reason, they start being redirected to Google US, which for us has higher latencies (avg: 400 ms).

How can I contact Google to fix this DNS Geolocation issue? Or, what can I do?

Comment: Which DNS resolvers are you using? Running your or relying on free DNS services? This redirection to US could be because of the customers using a different DNS resolver, one hosted in US maybe?

Comment: I'm using our DNS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you attempted to contact Google's NOC regarding this issue? As per Google's [PeeringDB](http://www.peeringdb.com/view.php?asn=15169) records, they can be contacted at noc [at] google [dot] com

Comment: thank you very much! Google NOC already answered me and is taking a look at the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your experiencing issues with google's GEO IP tool; you can fix this by going [here](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/request.py?contact_type=ip) where you can register your companies IP block with them and they'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob already linked to the correct place to get Geolocation data fixed.

Geolocation is done based on the address of your recursive DNS resolver, and not the IP of the host running a web browser.

Due to this, a workaround for this problem is:

- Find someone else nearby with a
  recursive resolver
- Test to see if www.l.google.com is
  being geolocated properly
- If so, configure your recursive
  nameserver to send all queries for
  google.com to the other recursive
  resolver with correct geolocation.